# Используется ли система событий в Unity для отслеживания Input?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я вот хочу избавиться от Update() и перенёс OnTriggerEnter2D в event. Могу ли я как-то ещё и Input туда перенести чтобы проверять на вхождение в триггер и через некоторое время нажатую в нём(триггере) кнопку? Или нужно прибегнуть к методу Update()? Мне кажется что нет такой системы, но на всякий спрошу.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Без метода Update() не получиться. В любом случае он будет использоваться. Можно создать свой event в Update() в отдельном скрипте. Также есть вариант с использованием "[NEW Input System Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html)" где можно задать события на нажатия кнопки.